# Using Jar files in intellji from maven repo

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

My goal is to be able to use the following -> OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

However Intellji still isn't recognizing it.

I have tried the following ->
1: Gone to
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp
and downloaded the latest version of the far file okhttp-5.0.0-alpha.11.jar
2: opened Intellij and sourced the file in the modules section.

Please help, I don't know what i am doing wrong?
[error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyzZ9.png)

[jar file add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M59w4.png)

I want to be able to make http requests so that i can use api's.

Comment: Did you forget to add the imports? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html. I would also use the release version of the library (`okhttp-4.10.0.jar`) unless you need some new features that are only available in 5.0 alpha.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the package:

`import com.squareup.ok http.OkHttpClient;`